# If the radius of a sphere is increased by $10\%$, by what percentage is its volume increased?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> **Question:** If the radius of a sphere is increased by $10\%$, by what percentage is its volume increased? Use Calculus.
>
> **Answer:** It increases by approximately $33.1\%$.

---

I did the above question using calculus but my answer came out to be 30%. Here's the solution. What is wrong in it?

---

$V = \frac{4}{3} πr^3$

$dV = \frac 4 3  π \cdot 3  r^2 dr$

$dV  = 4 π r^2 dr$

since

$dr = \frac{10}{100} r$

therefore

$dV = 4  π  r^2 \cdot \frac{10}{100}  r$

$dV = \frac 4 {10} π r^3$

now

$dV/V = [ \frac 4{10}  πr^3] / [ \frac 4 3  πr^3]$

$dV/V = 3/10$

and

$100dV/V = \frac 3{10} \times 100 = 30\%  $

Comment: Please use MathJax for formatting your math; as it is now, it is very hard to read.

Comment: You're using the 1st derivative to give an approximation. The given answer, $33.1\%$, is **exact**, not an approximation at all. Note that $$1.1^3 -1 = 0.331$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo But if no such approximation should take place, it is weird that the question asks for the use of calculus..

Comment: So probably they mean that you should use also the 2nd, and 3rd derivative, i.e. Taylor development, i.e. the **exact** answer

Comment: if you know that $V = 4/3 * \pi * r^3$

then why not just

$V = (4/3 * \pi * (1.1*r)^3) / (4/3 * \pi * r^3) = 1.1^3$

Answer (score 1):

we have $$V_1=\frac{4}{3}\pi \cdot r^3$$ then we get $$V_2=\frac{4}{3}\pi\cdot r^3\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)^3$$ and we get $$\frac{V_2}{V_1}=\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)^3$$

Answer (score 1):

The picture below shows you what you did wrong. You used the gradient function at a point $r_1$ and extrapolated that tangent line to approximate the value of $\frac 4 3 \pi r^3$ at a value $r_2$ which is 10% bigger than $r_1$. In the diagram below, the red line is the tangent line to $V$, which increases from $1$ to $1.3$ (as shown by the light green line) as $r$ increases from $r_1$ to $r_2=1.1\times r_1$. On the other hand, the value of the volume function (brown) at $r_2$ is $1.331$, as shown by the dotted blue line. There is a discrepancy between the two values because point $A$ is not in the same position as point $B$

[image: Graph]

The best way to solve your problem is simply to calculate the difference in the values of $V$ (from point $(0.62,1)$ to point $B$ in the diagram above): $$\frac{V(r_2)-V(r_1)}{V(r_1)}=\frac{\frac 4 3\pi (1.1r)^3 -\frac 4 3 \pi r^3}{\frac 4 3\pi r^3}=\frac{1.1^3-1}1=0.331=33.1\%$$ where $r_2=1.1\times r_1$.